# Setting datajoint key to a different variable in make fxn

Tags: datajoint

Wondering why and when it's needed to set the key to a different variable in a make/maketuples function in an auto-populated table in datajoint, as in the documentation [here](https://docs.datajoint.org/matlab/v3.4/computation/03-master-part.html).

In this example, the part table SegmentationROI is defined as follows:

```
%{
# Region of interest resulting from segmentation
-> test.Segmentation
roi  : smallint   # roi number
---
roi_pixels  : longblob   #  indices of pixels
roi_weights : longblob   #  weights of pixels
%}

classdef SegmentationROI < dj.Part
    properties(SetAccess=protected)
        master = test.Segmentation
    end
    methods
        function make(self, key)
            image = fetch1(test.Image & key, 'image');
            [roi_pixels, roi_weighs] = mylib.segment(image);
            for roi=1:length(roi_pixels)
                entity = key;
                entity.roi_pixels = roi_pixels{roi};
                entity.roi_weights = roi_weights{roi};
                self.insert(entity)
            end
        end
    end
end
```

What is the purpose of renaming the key as a separate variable, entity (entity = key), and then inserting that?

Comment: Thanks, Chris! Unfortunately I'm still confused--other examples in the documentation  (both matlab and python) add fields to the key and then insert the key dictionary itself. Is that not best practice? When is it a problem?

Comment: I would consider modification of the key *not* best practice in any case where the key might be used to structure the make function (e.g., for item in key, do X). If you look at the make functions within github.com/datajoint/element-array-ephys/blob/main/element_array_ephys/ephys.py, you'll see cases where we self.insert(key, other_args) rather than key=dict(key,other_args). I would recommend following this model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, we're adding fields to `entity` as a struct. I'd consider it best practice to preserve arguments a function as-is. If we added a second for-loop here, we might run into issues when calling `key` for another purpose.

*Caveat:* I'm more familiar with DataJoint python and have not used it extensively in MATLAB.